# how to set up username and passwords for different git repos?

Tags: password, git

```
─[$] cat ~/.gitconfig

[user]
    name = Shirish Agarwal
    email = xxxx@xxxx.xxx
[core]
    editor = leafpad
    excludesfiles = /home/shirish/.gitignore
    gitproxy = \"ssh\" for gitorious.org
[merge]
    tool = meld
[push]
    default = simple
[color]
    ui = true
    status = auto
    branch = auto
```

Now I want to put my git credentials for github, gitlab and gitorious so each time I do not have to lookup the credentials on the browser. How can this be done so it's automated ?

I am running zsh

Comment: This could be of help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884702/6242649 and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes

Just that in my case it always used the global credential.username even when there is one present at project level.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Using SSH

The common approach for handling git authentication is to delegate it to SSH. Typically you set your SSH public key in the remote repository (*e.g.* [on GitHub](https://github.com/settings/keys)), and then you use that whenever you need to authenticate. You can use a key agent of course, either handled by your desktop environment or manually with `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`.

To avoid having to specify the username, you can configure that in SSH too, in `~/.ssh/config`; for example I have

```
Host git.opendaylight.org
  User skitt
```

and then I can clone using

```
git clone ssh://git.opendaylight.org:29418/aaa
```

(note the absence of a username there).

## Using `gitcredentials`

If the SSH approach doesn't apply (*e.g.* you're using a repository accessed over HTTPS), git does have its own way of handling credentials, using [`gitcredentials`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) (and typically [`git-credential-store`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)). You specify your username using

```
git config credential.${remote}.username yourusername
```

and the credential helper using

```
git config credential.helper store
```

(specify `--global` if you want to use this setup everywhere).

Then the first time you access a repository, git will ask for your password, and it will be stored (by default in `~/.git-credentials`). Subsequent accesses to the repository will use the stored password instead of asking you.

***Warning***: This does store your credentials plaintext in your home directory. So it is inadvisable unless you understand what this means and are happy with the risk.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit about `credential.${remote}`  and `credential.helper`. Is there some documentation  you could point out as this is the first time I am reading about it.

Comment: I linked to the manpages in my answer, that's the documentation. `${remote}` is the protocol and hostname part of the URI you want to clone, `helper` points to a helper program.

Comment: There's also a [chapter of *Pro Git*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks @zahra_oveyedzade, it’s already included in the answer ;-).

Answer (score 12):

For those finding this later -- I had difficulties with this and finally made it work

https / credentials.helper / Ubuntu

1. Unset Globally:
   `git config --global --unset credentials.helper`
2. Unset locally: (In each repo) 
   `git config --unset credential.helper`
3. Create credential file for each repo: (inside each repo)

   ```
   git config credential.helper 'store --file ~/.git_reponame_credentials'
   ```

Not saying it is the best way or the only way - but it worked for me after several frustrating hours.

Comment: seems to be similar to what stephen kitt shared above.

Comment: @shirish not really, the third point was the one I needed - option to specify where the files is located.

Comment: @shirish; Also, Kitts instructions don't specify un setting the credentials, which was a crucial component for me since I had already set them globally.

Comment: I also had difficulty with this as it isn't as if all the git repos. you will get would be from the same source/store. The second one is better but much more frustating to work in reality. Still thank you for sharing. @SteveJ

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you have another account in github with those SSH keys. If that's the case:

1. Logout from github
2. Login with the another account
3. Remove the SSH keys
4. Logout from github
5. Login with your wanted user
6. Assign the SSH keys to the wanted user
7. Try again the git command, such as "git push"